How to add a transition animation in Expo Tabs?
In my expo app, i have this folder structure:

app
├── (tabs)
│   ├── _layout.jsx
│   ├── index.jsx
│   ├── settings.jsx

Here is a code snippet from _layout.jsx which uses expo-router:
const TabLayout = () => {
  return (<>
    <Tabs>
      <Tabs.Screen name="index"/>
      <Tabs.Screen name="settings"/>
    </Tabs>
  </>)
}

export default TabLayout

Now the code works as expected and i can see a navigation bar at the bottom of the screen, and I can switch tabs using it.
The problem is that there is no transition animation when I switch tabs.
How can I implement a simple slide animation?

Were you able to find your answer ? Also looking for one here...

Tabs does not have any property that allows transition animations, it is like Slot.
However, you can use react-native-reanimated to animate your screen input (you can do this for any screen)
For example, your index.jsx
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import Animated, {SlideInRight } from "react-native-reanimated";
import { useFocusEffect } from "expo-router";

const Index = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      setKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1);
    }, [])
  );

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black"}}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor: "black",
        }}
        key={key}
        entering={SlideInRight}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Index Screen</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Index;

If your Animated.View uses a non-white backgroundColor, set the backgroundColor to match your View.
You can see more Layout Animations in the documentation
I hope it is helpful to you!
